# Different elements in grid column

Tags: extjs, grid

Is it possible to have different elements in a Ext JS grid column? If yes, how can I do this? If no, is there another appropriate solution? Maybe with an example.

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards, shub

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by different elements exactly?

You could use a [TemplateColumn](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Template), and put in any markup and record values that you want

You could use the [.renderer()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) method to return any markup that you want

You could use the [.getRowClass()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-getRowClass) method to return a different css class depending on content

If you want to put an actual ExtJS component in a grid column, you should use Skirtle's [ComponentColumn](http://skirtlesden.com/ux/component-column)